# Logical port making mysql query too slow

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database with the following relationship:
[relationship](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wb5AG.png)

These tables link a customer to an address:
Cliente = client
Clientenendereco = Many to many table between Endereco (table) and Cliente (table)
Endereco = address
Endereco_rua = address_street
Endereco_cidade = address_city
Endereco_estado = address_state

The cardinality is:
Cliente NxN Endereco
Endereco 1x1 Endereco_rua
Endereco_rua 1x1 Endereco_cidade
Endereco_cidade 1x1 Endereco_state

And the query I use is:

```
SELECT cli.cliente_id, cli.cliente_cpf, cli.cliente_nome, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, 
cli.cliente_datanasc, CURDATE()) AS idade, ende.endereco_cep, ende.endereco_numero, 
ben.beneficio_numero, 
ben.beneficio_codigo, ben.beneficio_valor, ban.banco_cod, ab.banco_agencia_numero, 
cbb.conta_banco_numero, ben.beneficio_margem_emprestimo, ben.beneficio_margem_cartao 
FROM cliente AS cli 
RIGHT JOIN telefonencliente AS tnc FORCE INDEX(`fk_telefone_has_cliente_cliente1_idx`) 
ON tnc.cliente_id = cli.cliente_id 
RIGHT JOIN telefone AS tel 
ON tel.telefone_id = tnc.telefone_id 
INNER JOIN beneficio AS ben 
ON ben.cliente_id = cli.cliente_id  

LEFT JOIN clientenendereco AS ce 
ON ce.cliente_id = cli.cliente_id 
LEFT JOIN endereco AS ende 
ON ende.endereco_id = ce.endereco_id 
LEFT JOIN endereco_rua AS er 
ON er.endereco_rua_id = ende.endereco_rua_id 

LEFT JOIN endereco_cidade AS ec
ON ec.endereco_cidade_id = er.cidade_id
LEFT JOIN endereco_estado AS ee
ON ee.endereco_estado_id = ec.estado_id

LEFT JOIN banco_agencia AS ab 
ON ab.banco_agencia_id = ben.fk_banco_agencia_id 
LEFT JOIN conta_banco AS cbb 
ON cbb.conta_banco_id = ben.fk_conta_banco_id 
LEFT JOIN banco AS ban 
ON ban.banco_id = ben.fk_banco_id
WHERE ee.endereco_estado_id = 1 AND cli.cliente_id IS NOT NULL AND cli.cliente_id NOT 
IN(SELECT ci.cliente_id FROM cliente_inativo AS ci WHERE ci.cliente_id = cli.cliente_id) 
AND 
cli.cliente_id NOT IN (SELECT ma.cliente_id FROM mailing_alocado AS ma WHERE 
ma.cliente_id = cli.cliente_id) AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, cli.cliente_datanasc, 
CURDATE()) >=18 AND TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, cli.cliente_datanasc, CURDATE()) <=68 AND 
(ben.beneficio_datainicio BETWEEN '1990-01-01' AND '2007-12-31') 
GROUP BY cli.cliente_id
LIMIT 20000
```

When I use "ee.endereco_estado_id = 1" the query takes 2 minutes to return the records
On the other hand if I remove "ee.endereco_estado_id = 1" the query takes 0.068 seconds
Here with Explain:
[With "ee.endereco_estado_id = 1"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvBQZ.png)
[Without "ee.endereco_estado_id = 1"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxKrI.png)

I noticed that without the "ee.endereco_estado_id = 1" It starts with the table "ben", which is good, however, with the "ee.endereco_estado_id = 1" It starts with the table "ee" which takes a long time.
I don't know what to do anymore, because I need the records that are in state number 1, please help me I don't know what I can do or where is my error.

Tables:
endereco ~ 3milions rows
endereco_rua ~ 4milions rows
endereco_cidade ~ 21thousand rows
endereco_estado ~ 26 rows

Comment: that is a horrible query, but RUN an EXPLAIN and also ANALYSE and see if all the indexes are used. Some of the table seem to have 1:1 relationship, so that an left Join doesn't seem to be the right way. the way to go is to chek mysql error log if there is a error or warnung. And then start from Scratch by addidng one table after another and see if the results match the expectation. and find the problems

Comment: Why is it a horrible query? Thanks for the answer

Comment: joins need space and time to process so less joins are better for big databases, sub tables are usually smallish. still run explain and see if the are missing indexes last column

Comment: Ahh yes, you're right, in this case where one table depends on the other to get the data, which way would you recommend doing the query? in this case, clientenendereco->endereco->endereco_rua->endereco_cidade->endereco_estado

Comment: Your GROUP BY is invalid and expected to raise an error. (And will do so when upgrading to a newer MySQL version, unless in compatibility mode.)

Comment: RIGHT JOIN, LEFT JOIN mix... Who understands that combination?!? (Most people find `main table LEFT JOIN optional data` much easier to understand than `optional data RIGHT JOIN main table`.)

Comment: It worked when I removed Group By, but why is it problematic? And now I have duplicate records, how can I merge them? in this case, repeated customer lines

Comment: I arranged the joins for LEFT and added this query that I put above as a subquery and in the main query a GROUP BY:
SELECT vals.* FROM (SELECT cli.cliente_id, cli.cliente_cpf, cli.cliente_nome....) AS vals
GROUP BY vals.cliente_id
0.7 segs
And it worked very well!

Comment: It is recommended to start the chain of joins from the smallest/shortest table and then go up to the largest table in the list. Also, you may choose to replace some of the tables with subqueries so that you can move some of the WHERE conditions inside such subqueries and thus reduce the number of rows for each JOIN. For example, if you want `main table LEFT JOIN other table WHERE main.type_id = 3` then you can try `(SELECT * FROM main_table WHERE type_id = 3) AS main LEFT JOIN other ON ....`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try turning the query inside out to avoid the `GROUP BY`, which is probably causing some of the performance hangup.

```
SELECT ... ((lots of columns))
    FROM (
        SELECT cliente_id
            FROM client
            ((with the minimal JOINs and WHEREs to get the ids))
            ORDER BY .. LIMIT .. -- if needed
         ) AS ids
    JOIN client AS cli ON cli.cliente_id = ids.cliente_id
    JOIN (( all the other tables and WHEREs ))
    ORDER BY ..  -- if needed; note: the inner sort will be lost
```

I assume you indexes on the various columns in the `WHERE` clauses?  If not, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT...`

Please do not use `LEFT` when the 'right' table is not optional.  Example:  `ee.endereco_estado_id = 1`

Please say which JOINs are 1:1 vs 1:many vs many:1.  I need to understand whether the joining "explodes" the number of rows (only to have the `GROUP BY` implode them).  My suggested rewrite assumes that is happening.

Comment: thanks for the answer actually thanks everyone, i did what you said and used subquery

Comment: @Froslass And please share with us the time to run the query now that you have settled the dust.

Comment: @WilsonHauck approximately 0.07 seconds, I also improved based on subqueries, and, I could understand why the GROUP BY was the problem, thank you all!

Comment: @Froslass Congratulations, we are all in this together.  And we continue to learn, often.